# Is the Grothendieck group finite degree generated?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k-theory

For a scheme $X$ with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$, is the Grothendieck ring of locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules generated by the equivalence classes of rank $≤N$ modules, where $N$ is a sufficiently large integer? Is it true when $X$ is projective or furthermore $X$ is a projective variety?

Comment: Do you know if this is true for $X=\mathrm{Spec}A$?

Comment: No,but the cases I encountered are all true,for example:Dedekind ring,k[G] with G finite,though Noncommutitive.And I guess projectivity may make it closer to be true.

Comment: Please, use tex commands to make your question look reasonable.

Comment: @Aleko Robotis thanks forediting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is quasiprojective, the ring $K_0(X)$ is generated by vector bundles of rank at most $\dim(X)$.

Indeed, if $E$ is a vector bundle of rank $r > \dim(X)$ and $L$ is an ample line bundle, tensor product $E \otimes L^n$ is globally generated for $n \gg 0$, hence a general global section of $E$ has no zeroes, and hence there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \to L^{-n} \to E \to E' \to 0,
$$
where $E'$ is locally free of rank $r - 1$, and hence
$$
[E] = [L^{-n}] + [E'].
$$

Comment: great!thank you very much

Comment: And what about finitely generated?I know it is not true for elliptic curve But could you give me some conditions to make it true?

Comment: There is a surjective homomorphism $\det: K_0(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X)$. If $K_0(X)$ is finitely generated, then so is $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$. When $X$ is a smooth projective curve, $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ is the extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ by the group $J(k)$, where $J$ is the Jacobian, so it won’t be finitely generated in genus $g \geq 1$ over local fields. For $g=0$ (ie $X=\mathbb{P}^1$) or over number fields, though, this objection won’t work.